# Copy value and reduce code

Tags: jquery, copy

I copy values from input to other inputs with the same name:

```
$('input[name="pods_field_post_title"]').val($('#selected input[name="pods_field_post_title"]').val());
$('input[name="pods_field_name"]').val($('#selected input[name="pods_field_name"]').val());
$('input[name="pods_field_street"]').val($('#selected input[name="pods_field_street"]').val());
$('input[name="pods_field_city"]').val($('#selected input[name="pods_field_city"]').val());
```

How can I reduce this code? want to add fields dynamically and manually typing would not comfortable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code -

Use jQuery start with selector to iterate all input having name starts with `pods_field_post`

```
$('input[name^="pods_field_post"]').each(function(){
    var inputName = $(this).attr('name');
    var newVal = $('#selected input[name="'+inputName +'"]').val();
    $(this).val(newVal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To DRY it up you could put it in to a function passing the identifying name of the inputs as a parameter, something like this:

```
function copyValue(fieldName) {
    $('input[name="' + fieldName + '"]').val($('#selected input[name="' + fieldName + '"]').val());
}

copyValue('pods_field_post_title');
copyValue('pods_field_name');
copyValue('pods_field_street');
copyValue('pods_field_city');
```

You could also change the parameter to accept an array if there will be a lot of fields to copy in one instance:

```
function copyValues(fieldNames) {
    for (var i = 0; i < fieldNames.length; i++) {
        $('input[name="' + fieldNames[i] + '"]').val($('#selected input[name="' + fieldNames[i] + '"]').val());
    }
}

copyValues(['pods_field_post_title', 'pods_field_name', 'pods_field_street', 'pods_field_city']);
```